# Passing dictionary to a function

Tags: python

I'm trying to use dictionary values in a function and I keep getting a `NameError`. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
import re

def main():
    sales_amount = get_amount()
    customer_ID = get_ID()
    discounts = read_discounts()
    calculate_discount(sales_amount, discounts)
    print(discount_percentage)
    #print (discounts)

def get_amount():
    return float(input("Enter total sales amount: "))

def get_ID():
    return float(input("Enter customer ID: "))

#function to read discount values, strip non-alphanumeric characters and add values to dictionary
def read_discounts():
    myFile = open('discount.txt', 'r')
    discountValues = {}

    #read and split first line
    firstLine = myFile.readline()
    firstLine = re.sub(r'\$','',firstLine)
    firstLine = re.sub(r'\%','',firstLine)
    firstLine = firstLine.split()
    #add values to dictionary
    discountValues['UpperLimit1'] = {firstLine[2]}
    discountValues['UpperLimit1'] = [ float(x) for x in discountValues['UpperLimit1'] ]
    discountValues['PercentDiscount1'] = {firstLine[4]}
    discountValues['PercentDiscount1'] = [ float(x) for x in discountValues['PercentDiscount1'] ]

    return (discountValues)

def calculate_discount(sales_amount,discounts):

    if sales_amount < discountValues[UpperLimit1]: 
        discount_percentage = discountValues[PercentDiscount1]

main()
```

And here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\test.py", line 92, in <module>
main()
  File "C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\test.py", line 7, in main
calculate_discount(sales_amount, discountValues)
NameError: global name 'discountValues' is not defined
```

I've tried passing the dictionary name as an argument in the function but that yields the same results. Also I should note that I know my method for reading the text file into the dictionary probably isn't optimum but I'd like to focus on the `calculate_discount` function for the moment.

Full disclosure: this is for an assignment.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve *"I'd like to focus on the calculate_discount function for the moment."* - then **get rid of the rest of it**

Comment: it's just like the error says. `discountValues` is not defined in your main function. you don't define until `read_discounts` is called, and then only as a local variable within that function.

Comment: Your code's indentation is all messed up, please fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
discounts = read_discounts()
calculate_discount(sales_amount, discountValues)
```

You saved `discounts`. Use that instead of `discountValues`.

And again here:

```
def calculate_discount(sales_amount,discounts):

    if sales_amount < discountValues[UpperLimit1]: 
        discount_percentage = discountValues[PercentDiscount1]
```

Use names consistently.

Your `read_discounts()` method also appears to have improper indentation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried passing discounts instead and I still get the name error, pointing to the if statement in the function. Is it possible to use a dictionary between functions?

Comment: Again, your indentation is messed up. In Python, proper indentation is not optional. Fix it first.

Comment: I was just having issues pasting code into stack overflow. It is proper in the file itself. I know this is not great but do you have any advice regarding the dictionary? I'm just running low on time, any help would be greatly appreciated. EDIT: Sorry it should be fixed now.

Comment: Hi Tigerhawk. I think I fixed the naming consistency, however now I get a NameError pointing to the dictionary key that I try to invoke. Is there a particular method for using a dictionary value like this that I'm missing?

Comment: `def calculate_discount(sales_amount,discounts):  

    if sales_amount < discounts[UpperLimit1]: 
        discount_percentage = discounts[PercentDiscount1]`

Comment: I'm really sorry I'm struggling with the formatting here. I know its a pain

Comment: That's because the keys aren't variables named `UpperLimit1` and `PercentDiscount`, they're the strings `'UpperLimit1'` and `'PercentDiscount'`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78564/discussion-between-c3066521-and-tigerhawkt3).

Answer (score -1):

In your main function you are using variable "discountValues" in line:

```
calculate_discount(sales_amount, discountValues)
```

It has not been declared yet, If you intend to use the gloabl one use this statement inside the main() function.

```
def main():
    global discountValues
    ...
```

Comment: This is wrong. It's a variable name issue, not a scope issue.